# Bibliography+Word processing software on android?

Tags: file-management, word-processor

I used to use zotero+word 2016 on my windows laptop but it has since broke and I have a bluetooth keyboard and android tablet for now. What programs can I use to organise my bibliography that has an add on for android (preferably word 2016 on android) word processors?

Comment: What specific features do you need? You now there's a Zotero client for Android ([ZotDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=computer.benjamin.zotdr0id)) and several [office packages](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_office) as well. Also, what is your price margin?

Comment: ZotDroid is great (though a full zotero client would be better) and so is microsoft word is great (I work on docx). 

What I am asking for is a bibliography manager that has plugins for a word processor to does automatic citation. Looking for a pair that will have the functionality of word+zotero but on android.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know any that works on docx (I prefer open standards ;) If I remember correctly, [Mendeley](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mendeley) might come close – but it doesn't seem to work with docx (just PDF if I see that correctly). Same for [F1000Workspace](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.f1000.workspace) it seems. So sorry, no real good match from my end.